# QT Mplwidget, plot with blitting

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, widget, blit

I'm a python beginner, and I'm developing my first GUI using QtDesigner to draw serial port reads to HF data.

I have added four widgets to it. I'm using matplotlib.animation class, but I found that if I start four plots at the same time, the GUI becomes much less responsive, I think it's because of the large amount of data to draw, because if I start four plots at the same time, I have to draw a total of 3600 data points, and I'm using canvas.draw(), the coordinates of each time will also be will be redrawn each time.

I tried to use blitting to speed up the drawing now, but it didn't work.

Here is a plotting program, maybe you can help me, I would be very grateful!

```
def start_animation_2(self):
    if self.freeze_plot2:
        # self.ani3.pause()
        self.ani2.event_source.stop()
    else:
        self.ani2 = FuncAnimation(
            self.view.MplWidget2,
            self.update_view2,
            interval=300,
            cache_frame_data=False,
            blit=True,
        )
        self.view.MplWidget2.canvas.draw()


def update_view2(self, frame_data=None):

    package_info = self.get_package_info()
    self.subrecord_data = self.notify_new_data()

    ax = self.view.MplWidget2.canvas.axes
    unit = constants.Units.get(package_info[4][1], "")

    ax.clear()
    ax.grid(True)

    line = ax.plot(self.subrecord_data[1][-900:])
    ax.set_xlabel("Data points")
    ax.set_ylabel(f"{package_info[4][1]} ({unit})")

    return (line,)


class MplWidget2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())

        vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        vertical_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.canvas.axes = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas.axes.grid(True)
        self.canvas.figure.set_size_inches(8, 6)
        self.canvas.figure.subplots_adjust(
            left=0.075, right=0.95, bottom=0.19, top=0.95
        )
        self.setLayout(vertical_layout)
```

Comment: Post a [mre] and debugging details such as timing information on the bottleneck. Rendering just 3600 points should take much shorter than 300 ms. And I don't recommend blitting in this case. Just reuse one ```Line2D``` instance with ```Line2D.set_data()```.